# sending value of NSString to ViewController PopOver

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller

Im looking to access the value of an NSString from the parent ViewController inside the PopOver View Controller.  Below is the code i have that generates the popover when selecting a row from a tableView.  I need to be able to access the varToPass value in the editPersonViewController.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIView *anchorr = tableView;
    UIViewController *viewControllerForPopover =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editPersonViewController"];

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
               initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchorr.frame
                             inView:anchorr.superview
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


    Person *person = [arrayOfPersons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    // I Need to Send/Access This Value In editPersonViewController
    NSString *varToPass = person.personID;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a public property in your editPersonViewController.h file called personID like so

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *personID;
```

Then, just reorder your instantiation of the editViewController to look like this:

```
UIView *anchorr = tableView;
Person *person = [arrayOfPersons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
EditPersonViewController *viewControllerForPopover =
(EditPersonViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editPersonViewController"];

viewControllerForPopover.personID= person.personID;

popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
           initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchorr.frame
                         inView:anchorr.superview
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: The key line is viewControllerForPopover.personID= person.personID;

Comment: im getting personID not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'?

Comment: You need to add @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *personID; to your .h file for that viewController (i.e. whichever UIViewController that has the restoration identifier of "editPersonViewController")

Comment: You need to cast the viewControllerForPopover as the class you put the property on. [(EditPersonViewController*)viewControllerForPopover personID]

Comment: Good catch, and even instead of saying UIViewController *viewControllerForPopover , you should say EditPersonViewController *viewControllerForPopover